# Error when create array in php

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$id = '1,2,3,4,5';
$name = 'Iphone 3,Iphone 3S,Iphone 4,Iphone 4S,Iphone 5';
$id_arr = array($id);
$name_arr = array($name);
$arr = array_combine($id_arr, $name_arr);
print_r($arr);
```

When I `print_r($arr)` is result is `([1,2,3,4,5] =>'Iphone 3,Iphone 3S,Iphone 4,Iphone 4S,Iphone 5')`

How to fix this is the result `([1]=>'Iphone 3' [2] => 'Iphone 3S' ... [5]=>'Iphone 5')`

Answer (score 2):

The correct function to use given that input is `explode`. `str_split` has unneeded overhead.
`$id_arr = explode(',', $id);`.
 Note that arrays should actually be defined like so: `$id_arr = array(1 => 'value 1', 2 => 'value 2', 3 => 'value 3');` etc... unless you are forced to use a string as the key set.

Comment: PHP will handle type casting anyway. So `$arr['1']` and `$arr[1]` can be considered the same unless a strict equality sign `===` is used.

Comment: Yes, I know; but why would you want to degrade performance (however little) to do something that is unneeded?

Comment: Totally agreed. You will need to use a loop to convert those into integers, though, which I would personally do anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

or try :

```
$id = '1,2,3,4,5';
$name = 'Iphone 3,Iphone 3S,Iphone 4,Iphone 4S,Iphone 5';
$id_arr = explode(',',$id);
$name_arr =explode(',',$name);
$arr = array_combine($id_arr, $name_arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have to start your array with 1 but if you want to maintain such order and keep keys as integers it can be done like this:

```
$name = 'Iphone 3,Iphone 3S,Iphone 4,Iphone 4S,Iphone 5';

$parts = explode(',', $name);

$arr  = array();

$i = 1;

foreach($parts as $value)
{
    $arr[$i] = $value;//we can possibly strip leading spaces and convert string case
    $i++;
}

print_r($arr);
```